# Condition not getting properly evaluated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function disabler(){
    var content = document.getElementById("show").textContent;
    var correct = "Roll Number Correct";
    var incorrect = "Roll Number Incorrect";
    alert(content == correct);
    /* if (){
        alert(content);
    } */ 
}
```

I have checked the value of the content variable ( which is as same as the correct variable)and used the typeof operator to be sure of its type. To my knowledge, the alert should yield true but it is not. What could be the possible solutions?

Comment: Are you sure the `content` is `correct`? There could be extra whitespace or something.

Comment: `console.log(content);` and post output

Comment: Maybe has somenting extra whitespace try using `document.getElementById("show").textContent.trim()`

Comment: Yeah, without seeing what's coming in from #show, there's no way of knowing. Code is technically fine, probably just a data issue

Comment: Post your HTML for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some white space. Check this example:

```js
var content = document.getElementById("show").textContent;

var contentWithTrim = document.getElementById("show").textContent.trim();


console.log(content);
console.log(contentWithTrim);

console.log("content.length:", content.length);
console.log("contentWithTrim.length:", contentWithTrim.length);

console.log(content == contentWithTrim);

console.log(content == "My Content");
console.log(contentWithTrim == "My Content");
```

```html
<div id="show">
   My Content
</div>
```

Comment: Also, it's useful trick is to check `content.length` and `contentWithTrim.length`, because it might be hard to spot the whitespace  characters when logged otherwise.